# Why do my XY cordinates not make sense / show up in ArcGIS 9.3?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcgis-9.3

In the Add XY Data menu I selected to add a table containing UTME and UTMN coordinates. I selected a WGS84 projection b/c that's what the GPS device that meade the readings was set to use. However, my raster map (and other features) in ArcGIS use a NAD_1983_StatePlane_North_Carolina_FIPS_3200_Feet projection. As a result (I assume), when I add my XY data layer, it doesn't show up anywhere on the existing map.

My first attempt to fix this was to re-project the new XY points:

- I tried the **Project tool**, and chose to project from WGS84_UTM_Zone_17S to NAD_1983_StatePlane_North_Carolina_FIPS_3200_Feet using NAD_1983_To_WGS_1984_5 as my geographic transformation.
- The values of my X and Y columns did not change, and the points still don't seem to exist on my map.

My second attempt to fix this was to convert my new XY points from meters into feet (US) [since the other layers are in a 'feet' pojection.

- I tried converting this reprojected layer from meters to feet (Using the "**Calculate Geometry**" option in the attribute table).
- It converted my UTME to a sensible number (from 689583.7 to 2744074), but the UTMN conversion makes no sense (from 4008525 to -52330979).

**What am I doing wrong and/or what can I do to make this work?**

Note:nearby points already on my existing map have coordinates {2032037.05127, 892767.424497}

Below are the properties of (first) my added XY points, (second) my underlying raster DEM map, and (third) the foot-converted reprojected XY data.

```
Data Type: XY Event Source
Location: C:\Users\paynec\Desktop
Table: H23 Geocoordinates2.csv
X Field: UTME
Y Field: UTMN
Has Object-ID Field: No

Projected Coordinate System:    WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_17S
Projection:          Transverse_Mercator
False_Easting:       500000.00000000
False_Northing:      10000000.00000000
Central_Meridian:    -81.00000000
Scale_Factor:        0.99960000
Latitude_Of_Origin:  0.00000000
Linear Unit:         Meter

Geographic Coordinate System:   GCS_WGS_1984
Datum:          D_WGS_1984
Prime Meridian: Greenwich
Angular Unit:   Degree

###############################################

Spatial_Reference:    NAD_1983_StatePlane_North_Carolina_FIPS_3200_Feet
Linear_Unit:          Foot_US (0.304801)
Angular_Unit:         Degree (0.017453292519943295)
False_Easting:        2000000.002616666
False_Northing:       0
Central_Meridian:     -79
Standard_Parallel_1:  34.33333333333334
Standard_Parallel_2:  36.16666666666666
Latitude_Of_Origin:   33.75
Datum:                D_North_American_1983

###############################################

Projected Coordinate System:    NAD_1983_StatePlane_North_Carolina_FIPS_3200_Feet
Projection: Lambert_Conformal_Conic
False_Easting:  2000000.00261667
False_Northing: 0.00000000
Central_Meridian:   -79.00000000
Standard_Parallel_1:    34.33333333
Standard_Parallel_2:    36.16666667
Latitude_Of_Origin: 33.75000000
Linear Unit:    Foot_US

Geographic Coordinate System:   GCS_North_American_1983
Datum:  D_North_American_1983
Prime Meridian:     Greenwich
Angular Unit:   Degree
```

Comment: Looks like you're using the wrong UTM zone, the 'S' in 'Zone 17S' is for South, as in south of the equator.

Comment: @DanC, though that's what I figured when I first saw 17S, my GPS (as well as many other Southeast US gps points I've seen) specify "17 S." Is this referring to something else??

Comment: I can't say, but UTM Zone 17S is in the southern hemisphere and your AOI is not, so whatever else may be going on, the first thing you need to resolve is to make sure that the coordinate system your GPS is using is correct and that the Event layer you create from it is set to use the same system.

Comment: Well, changing to 17 N definitely put the points on my map :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your GPS is most likely set in USNG coordinates, hence the 17 S. [PDF of USNG Chart here](https://www.fgdc.gov/usng/educational-resources/Map_USA_USNG_20081231.pdf)

[image]

You are currently selecting UTM Zone 17S as your original coordinate system, placing points in that zone ([More on UTM Zone 17S here](http://www.spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84-utm-zone-17s/)):

[image]

When running the project tool, you need to use the correct coordinate system, which I am assuming is USNG 17S, since you mention North Carolina in your question as well as 17 S on your GPS. See also: [Converting USNG Coordinates in ArcGIS 9.3](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Using_the_Convert_Coordinates_in_File_function) and [Instructions in 10.2, including Python Sample](http://help.arcgis.com/En/Arcgisdesktop/10.0/Help/index.html#//0017000000tw000000)

Comment: This is a great answer. The only caveat to all of this is that the GPS device says it's recording GPS units using WGS84 (not USNG). Unless these two are related??

Comment: @theforestecologist WGS84 is the datum that the GPS system and satellites use internally. Although you can often change the settings of a handheld GPS unit so it displays other units on-screen, it's still using WGS84 internally and recording data in that format.

Comment: @DanC ok thanks. I totally believe you, but could you provide a reference demonstrating this (so that I oculd reference it later)?

Comment: also as a follow-up: So I basically treat the data as WGS84 in zone 17N when reprojecting to NAD83? (Just with the additional realization that 17S in NC makes no sense in WGS84 and therefore is just a representation of UTMs  in USNG on the GPS's screen?)

Comment: Yes, Treating it as WGS84 should be sufficient to getting things converted as you need :)

Comment: Thanks so much! This  stuff just keeps getting more and more confusing! :p

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, the 17 S *is* intentional on the part of the GPS device, and it has nothing to do with the USNG (though @MaryBeth, please keep your answer posted). The company of the device contacted me and said the zone is based off of the **UTM *Grid* Zones of the World** and sent me the following [map](http://www.dmap.co.uk/utmworld.htm):

[image: Grid Zones of the World]

Zone 17S of the UTM *grid* zones overlays NC in the United states, which led to my initial confusion.

MaryBeth's answer (and Dan C's comments) though remain valid in that when it comes to ArcGIS I still have to treat the coordinates as WGS84 and use zone 17N of the WGS84 zone system. In this zoning system, *N* and *S* refer to *northern* and *southern* hemispheres respectively (vs. the C through X latitudinal grids in the grid zone of the UTM map).

Comment: @Marybeth 's answer remains valid because the "Grid Zone" in your map is *identical* to the top level of the [USNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_National_Grid), because both are derived from [MGRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_grid_reference_system) (which is based, in part, on [UTM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system)).  That last link explains: "Latitude bands are not a part of UTM, but rather a part of MGRS".

Comment: @Vince. Thank you. That's the last piece of all of this. Thanks for tying it together for me